# *Why* does global warming lead to more extreme weather events?

Tags: temperature, geophysics, weather, climate-science

I read several times about global warming leading to more exteme weather events, i.e. flooding, droughts and even winter storms occuring at higher rates and with more intensity.

So, higher temperature supposedly leads to an increase in the **variance** of the probability distribution of the weather.

This is not obvious at all. Naively, one might think that climate change would just shift the temperatures by several degrees.

*So, is there any **physical mechanism**, explaining the increase in the variance of the weather?*

I thought about the equilibrium vapor pressure of water at higher temperatures but I did not come useful conclusions.

Btw, a standard physical model is the damped harmonic oscillator. Is there any similar model to demonstrate the effects of globabl warming or meteorolgy and climate change? I'm thinking of something like a closed box with stone islands and water under some radiation.

Comment: Your initial logic is incorrect; changing the average can greatly increase the probability of rare events without changing the variance.  Look at a Gaussian distribution; suppose a +3 $\sigma$ event has a 1/1000 chance of happening.  Now, shift the whole distribution by 1 $\sigma$.  After the shift, the +3 $\sigma$ event is merely a +2 $\sigma$ event, with a 23/1000 chance of happening.  No change in the variance is needed.

Comment: You could also try here: https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @KenWharton MichaelS' logic is correct, equilibrium at *any* temperature is still an equilibrium, see, Essex, McKitrick, Andresen: "Does a Global Temperature Exist?" J. Non-Equilib. Thermodyn. 2007 Vol. 32 pp. 1–27, 10.1515/JNETDY.2007.001

Comment: This also seems a pretty broad question as textbooks in their entirety cover this subject. You may want to check out [this Q&A](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/775497/25301) (whenever it is that it gets an answer) for such material.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Climate scientists are clear that predictions for how much the mean temperature will increase are [more solid than predictions about changes in the variance](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.wace.2016.11.002), but as @Ken-Wharton noted in his comment, it only takes an increase in the mean to greatly increase the probability of formerly rare extreme high events.  As long as the mean keeps increasing, it is expected that new extreme high records will continue to be broken, even if the variance does not increase.

The growing frequency of high-temperature events is determined mostly by the increase in the Earth's mean temperature, but the frequency of heavy-precipitation events depends much more on changes in the temperature variance. As stated by [van der Wiel, R. Bintanja](https://doi.org/10.1038/s43247-020-00077-4) "projections of temperature extremes are more robust than those of precipitation extremes, since the mean climate is better understood than climate variability."

That said, it is not hard to imagine how increasing temperature could increase variance.  If you pump more energy into a system, more stuff can happen.  For example, if you heat a gas, both the mean energy and energy variance of the molecules increase, following a [Maxwell–Boltzmann distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell%E2%80%93Boltzmann_distribution).  Non-linear effects can dramatically increase variance for even small increases in the mean - think what happens to water as you heat it from 99°C to 100°C.

Most climate non-linearities are (we hope) not as dramatic as water boiling, but are still significant.  Where I live, the weather variance increases dramatically in summer as higher daily mean temperatures increase convection and evaporation that drive thundercloud formation.

To give an example of a mechanism that might drive more extremes, consider the possible consequences of polar sea ice melting as the Earth warms.  The change between white reflective sea ice and dark absorptive water causes the the [polar regions to warm much faster](https://doi.org/10.1038/s43247-022-00498-3) than the lower latitudes. This reduces the north-south atmospheric temperature differences that drive global air circulation and this might reduce the velocity of the jet streams. Slower jet streams could increasingly meander, [more frequently bringing extreme cold air](https://time.com/6259746/colder-winter-storms-climate-change-polar-vortex/) from the north and extreme hot air from the south, increasing the weather variance.

Modelling the Earth in a box is challenging because weather and climate have such large scales. I could heat or cool any plausible sized box with stone islands and water as much as I want, and although I might learn some interesting physics, I don't think I'd ever produce a [thunderstorm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thunderstorm), a [hurricane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tropical_cyclone), a [Hadley cell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadley_cell), or a spontaneous [jet stream](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jet_stream). There are methods, however, to experimentally study physics relevant to climate issues such [large-scale circulation and climate dynamics](https://doi.org/10.3390/atmos14050836), but that requires a bit fancier kit.

Comment: Indeed. Two further points that make things worse than 'expected': (1) maximum water content in air (100% relative humidity) increases non-linearly, so a slight temperature increase is a larger water carrying capacity increase. (2) Measurements of rainfall, for example, are not a Gaussian distribution (you don't have negative rainfall).

Answer (score 1):

Global warming is having its greatest effect at the poles. The poles are warming more than in the mid latitudes. This means that the temperature variation between the poles and the mid latitudes is reducing. Because of this in the upper jet stream, or what we would call the 500 millibar level we are seeing a significant flattening of the normal curve from north to south that normally occurs. What is happening is that the curve is remaining in place for much longer. So it is not necessarily that the temperature is greater, but rather that the greater temperature is remaining in place for longer, or a lower temperature or a low pressure with the resulting rain is remaining in place longer. So for example where I live in Victoria Canada we are seeing a long hot and very dry summer. In other locations they are seeing extreme rain events that last for days or weeks. So it is not that the days are hotter, or wetter, but rather that the hotter or wetter days are remaining in place for much longer. This was long predicted by scientists. The curves at the 500 millibar level used to race around the world quite quickly but now they are sticking in place for longer periods of weeks.

Answer (score 1):

One can get most of the way there without any physics.

If a place that usually gets a certain amount of water gets significantly more water, it will flood. If a place that usually gets a certain amount of water gets significantly less water, it's a drought. So if droughts and floods both count as severe weather, and climate change implies change in the amount of water that places get, climate change causes more severe weather almost by definition.